# WebClient of CXF throws NPE when query param value is null

Tags: web-services, cxf, jax-rs

I am using version 2.7.11 of all Apache CXF dependencies.

I am creating an instance of org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.

```
  Map<String, String> queryParams = new HashMap<>();
  queryParams.put("param1", null);
  for ( String param : queryParams.keySet() ) {
        webClient.query(param, queryParams.get(param));
  }
```

I am getting NullPointerException in the call to query() method

Following is stack trace

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.addMatrixQueryParamsToBuilder(AbstractClient.java:686)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.query(WebClient.java:647)

Comment: 1) Did you initialize `webClient`? 2) Post the stacktrace please.

Comment: Yes I did initialized web client. I had updated my post with stack trace. Additionally I also get some internal error if I try passing  an empty string "" as param value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the WebClient API does not expect the parameter value to be "null"